# Need to create a drop down list in laravel, and insert the results in a new database

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am new to laravel, I have a two tables: users, selected_users both contains id, name.
I wanted to create a drop down list that is populated from users, when selecting a user name it will insert the user's name beside the drop down menu. 
When I press submit the name should be saved to the selected_user table.

Can please someone help with this code how to write it in the view and controller.

Comment: Why not just have a `selected` `boolean` column in the `users` table? What's your goal with this?

Comment: I have page conating more than one field, in each field i need to create this drop down list to select the users so others can see who is selected when they open the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quiet sure what you really want to achieve but try the code below;

**userview.blade.php**

```
  <div class="container">
   @if(session('success'))
      <h1>{{session('success')}}</h1>
   @endif
   <form method="POST" action="{{route('save.selected-user')}}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="form-group row">    
       <div class="col-sm-8">
       <select class="form-control" id="selectUser" name="user_selected" required focus>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select user</option>        
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  </div>
<label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"  id="displayUser">Show selected User 
  here</label>
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mytextbox = document.getElementById('displayUser');
  var mydropdown = document.getElementById('selectUser');
  mydropdown.onchange = function(){
      mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
     mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
     }
  </script>
```

**TestController.php** (make sure you have User model and SelectedUser model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\SelectedUser;

class TestController extends Controller
{

  public function populateUsers()
  {
    $users = User::all();
    return view('test.userview', compact('users'));
  }

  public function saveUser(Request $rq)
  {
    $selectedUser = new SelectedUser;
    $selectedUser->name = $rq->user_selected;
    $selectedUser->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Selected Username added successfuly');
  }
}
```

**WEB.php**

```
Route::get('/selected-user', 'TestController@populateUsers');
Route::POST('/selected-user', 'TestController@saveUser')->name('save.selected-user');
```

Please let me know if it works

Comment: thanks for your help, really appreciate it, but the code stores the id not the name.

Comment: @mpsycho, from what I understand, you want to save the name instead of the ID? Please tell me more.

Comment: what i meant the above code stored the id, anyway i changed this line <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{ $user->name }}</option> to this <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{ $user->name }}</option> and it stored the name correctly, thanks again :)

Comment: Good jod. But it is always better to use the id(primary key) instead of the name and you will have to fetch name via its id in the VIEW.

Comment: Thanks for this! I noticed though that there should be a closing </form> and </div> tag after <input type="submit" value="Save">.